# Run method from another class to scroll listbox to bottom

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to autoscroll WPF ListBox to bottom automatically. I have two classes - one is Timer.cs and another one is MainWindow.xaml.cs

Here is Timer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Importer_WPF
{
    class Timer
    {
        public static readonly string MinutesExecution = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesExecution"];
        static System.Threading.Timer timer;

        public static void StartTimer()
        {

            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(MinutesExecution));

            timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {

                Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_ => App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainWindow.Names.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString())));

                MainWindow.AutoScroll(); // Problem is here

            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

        }

        public static void StopTimer()
        {
            timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Importer_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }
        public static bool IsCheckedYes { get; set; }

        [Obsolete]
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void AutoScroll()
        {
            int itemCount = ConsoleOutput.Items.Count - 1;
            if (itemCount > -1)
                ConsoleOutput.ScrollIntoView(ConsoleOutput.Items[itemCount]);
        }

    }
}
```

Debugger is giving this message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'MainWindow.AutoScroll()'

Any hints how to edit code structure so it will not produce errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the instance of mainwindow class which is in memory.

```
       ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).AutoScroll();
```